# Parity: Is deleting ~/.ethash folder also deletes chain data?

Tags: parity

I am not doing any mining and I want to clean unnessary files due to my limited memory space. I realized that `~/.ethash` folder contains around 3.5 GiB. I am not sure should we keep it for the chain-data syncing process.

```
~/.ethash$ ls
full-R23-0000000000000000  full-R23-5a46dd85298b0bef  full-R23-7e7d8bef9d86983a  light

/.ethash$ du -h
45M ./light
3.6G    .
```

**[Q]** When I remove `~/.ethash` folder does it also removes Parity's chain-data?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `~/.ethash` folder is for [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) data and it is needed for mining purposes only. Parity stores chain's data by default into the `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains` folder.

Comment: It's `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains` now.